# Orientdb crash logs fill up entire drive

Tags: java, orientdb

Our OrientDB server (version 2.2.17) crashes often. The Java VM creates massive hs_err_pid.log files. After about 3 crashes, it filled up our entire hard drive on our server with 78 gigs of crash logs.

These crash logs serves no purpose because they are to big to share and their only purpose is to fill hard drive space and make OrientDB crash even more.

I read on Oracle's website that we can use **-XXdumpSize:small**

```
-XXdumpSize:small
```

This won't dump the entire heap but only log the basic error.
How do I enable this for OrientDB?

I tried passing it in the **/etc/init.d/orient** launch script but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in `server.sh` file but I think would be much better if you create an issue in OrientDB tracker. So development team will fix your crashes.

Comment: The OrientBD team won't fix issues if it can't be reproduced. Since I can't reproduce the crashes, it's pointless. I tried adding it to the server.sh file but I'm not sure where. I added it to ORIENTDB_OPTS_MEMORY but it does not seem to have any effect. However, it difficult to assess because we were forced to take the DB offline because of an unrelated index issue. Will feed back as soon as I know what's going on.

Comment: Hi @anber I think we will try to fix it, you have at least error report. So we can look at it and maybe we will be able to do something with that.So we really looking forward to see this issue.

Comment: Sadly we don't have any error reports. We started cleaning our logs after every restart and we are in the process of changing our server configuration. OrientDB is too unreliable in distributed mode and we have been trying for months to get it stabilized without success. We have split our DB up into various other DB's with hourly backups. It seems to work better than replication. I just want to guarantee that the java vm dumps don't fill up our drives.

Comment: I see. If DB  crashes again, please preserve logs we will do all that we can to fix your issue and will very appreciate if you fill an issue. Also maybe you already noticed that but usually between -XX and command you should put space may be you missed that and as result dumps were not small.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at the spaces and give feedback. I hope it's that simple.